Why a object of custom class can be the key of a dict, while the list can not in Python?
class MyClassA:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

class MyClassB:
    def __init__(self, value=0, list_=[]):
        self.value = value
        self.list = list_
        
a = MyClassA()
b = MyClassB()
c = []

dict_ = {}
dict_[a] = 1 # No error
dict_[b] = 1 # No error
dict_[c] = 1 # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'


Is the object of MyClassA / MyClassB immutable?
list is also a kind of object. So why it becomes unhashable?
I'm quite confused about it.


It's documented in the glossary: Most of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not; immutable containers (such as tuples and frozensets) are only hashable if their elements are hashable. Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default. They all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their id().

dict keys need to be hashable, which requires implementing __hash__ method.
By default, objects implement id-based hash function. Hash has little meaning for mutable objects though, so it is removed from implementation of built-in classes of such types. You can do the same with custom classes by assigning None to the method:
class MyClassA:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
    __hash__ = None
dict_[MyClassA()] = 1 # TypeError: unhashable type: 'MyClassA'

As to question 1 - no, you can change values of A.value and B.value and B.list so they are not immutable.
Side notes:

You probably shouldn't set list as default value of parameter - "Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument
Don't call your variables with names of built-ins, e.g self.list.


Thanks a lot! So mutability and hashability should be the same (mutable object should be unhashable), but in the user-defined objects, they are not the same which does not seem make sense.

MyClassA : objects can be used as dictionary keys because they are immutable (they don't have any mutable attributes that can change).
MyClassB : objects can also be used as dictionary keys, even though they contain a list as an attribute, because the instance itself is hashable due to its immutability (the list being mutable doesn't affect the hashability of the instance).
However, a list c cannot be used as a dictionary key because lists are mutable and thus not hashable.
Mutability: Lists in Python are mutable, meaning their contents can change after they've been created. For example, you can append, remove, or modify elements in a list. On the other hand, objects of custom classes (MyClassA and MyClassB) are mutable or immutable depending on how they are implemented. In your example, both MyClassA and MyClassB objects are mutable because they have attributes that can be modified.
Hashability: In Python, keys in a dictionary must be hashable. Hashability essentially means that an object can be converted into an integer value (its hash) that remains the same throughout its lifetime and is used to quickly compare dictionary keys. Immutable types, such as strings, numbers, and tuples, are hashable. Mutable types, such as lists, sets, and dictionaries themselves, are not hashable.
